# How to save current activity's status when some other activity comes to the foreground

Tags: android, android-activity, state

I am building my first android app, which is a board game consisting of ImageViews (draggable), ToggleButton (turns sound ON/OFF), TextViews (for scores), ArrayList, booleans, integers, strings, floats, and some doubles. If I press back button to go to main menu, and try to come back to the game I was playing, it crashes. I am not implementing any of onPause, onStop, onRestart, onResume. I have only implemented onCreate. I went through few posts in this site, but all answers were confusing. Shoud I be using onPause and onResume OR onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState to save my current game state (all the data types and objects). An example would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

#### My Logcat

```
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.baghchalNepal/com.example.baghchal.UserAsTiger}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2851)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3435)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3306)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3251)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3227)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at com.example.baghchal.UserAsTiger.makeGoatMove(UserAsTiger.java:683)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at com.example.baghchal.UserAsTiger.onResume(UserAsTiger.java:297)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1202)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5328)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2841)
09-12 16:13:06.326: E/AndroidRuntime(14207):    ... 12 more
```

#### Java Code

```
    // create ImageView object to store a goat.
    ImageView thisGoat = null;          
    
    // This method call receives safest position where a goat can be placed.
    Point bestPoint = getBestPointToPlaceGoat();

    // if there are goats remained to be placed on the board, select a goat to be moved to the board.
    for (int i=0; i<imageArrayList.size(); i++) {
        if ((imageArrayList.get(i).getX() == (xMin+70)) &&  (imageArrayList.get(i).getY() == (yMin-200))){
            thisGoat = imageArrayList.get(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    // move the goat, if a goat was selected from above.
    if (thisGoat != null) {         

         // Here I am removing the ImageView obj
        relativeLayout.removeView(thisGoat);  

        thisGoat.setX(bestPoint.getX()-70);
        thisGoat.setY(bestPoint.getY()-70);
        bestPoint.setOccupiedBy("goat");            
        
         // this is where error is acc. to logcat
        relativeLayout.addView(thisGoat);           
    }
```

Comment: - A: you should use the Activity lifecycle methods to save any data and clean up any resources that are in use when your Activity undergoes a state change.

 - B: What is the error you're receiving?  Can you post a Logcat?

Comment: do you mean onPause, onStop,... by Activity lifecycle methods? I am not really using any special resource, just the RAM i guess by storing the data types and objects as I stated in my question.

I have added the logcat error on my original question.

Comment: As per your Logcat: the error is in line 683 of the UserAsTiger class.  Look for the line in the Logcat that says Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: check it out, i added a snippet of the code where the error occured, and I am removing the view from the layout before adding it.

Comment: How are you removing the view?  In the above code, what line is the one mentioned in the error?

Comment: like this: 

relativeLayout.removeView(thisGoat);

I have added comment to show you where i have removed the view and where logcat pointed the error.

Answer (score 0):

> If I press back button to go to main menu, and try to come back to the game I was playing, it crashes.

If the only problem is when you press the back button, as you stated, then you can just override the back button and save data there

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // save your data here using SharedPrefs, DB, or however you need
}
```

You won't need to implement `onResume()` as your `Activity` will be killed and `onCreate()` will be called again where you can check for stored data and reinstate your values.

If you are worried about when another `Activity` comes in the foreground but the current `Activity` is still on the stack then you can override `onPause()` in the same manner and save the data in that function.

If these don't help then, as stated in a comment by Prmths, post your logcat so we can see what the error is.

[Activity Docs with lifecycle example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: yes, it happens only when I hit the back button to go to main menu, and then again hit the game button to continue the game. I guess, according to you, I should be okay if I implement onBackPressed(). I don't really need to save on the DB, so I guess SharedPrefs is the wtg.

Comment: Now seeing your logcat, you may need to call `removeView()` to remove whatever view you are trying to add (call it on the Views parent). If this doesn't solve your problem then you will need to post some of the relevant code

Comment: check it out, i added a snippet of the code where the error occured, and I am removing the view from the layout before adding it.

Comment: @amir0220 This only happens when you press back button? If so, put `relativeLayout.removeView(thisGoat)` in `onBackPressed()` and make both of those variables member variables.

Comment: Besides my above comment, always be careful when using goats. They can be very sneaky

Comment: relativeLayout.removeView(thisGoat) didn't really solve the issue. I was able to get back to the activity without error, but it created an extra ImageView object and messed up the application logic. Plus the location of each goats/tigers, scores were not restored. How would I do that. onPause() and onResume() or onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() ?

Answer (score -1):

These methods will be use full for you

You can use **SharedPreferences** to save data and **onResume** get it back
Learn more from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{       
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
}
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    // Save your data here
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);       
     // REtrieve your data heve
}
```

You shall learn more about [Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

[image]

Comment: I do understand all these, and I do have these methods on my activities just with the call to the super methods, and that's not doing any help.

Comment: @amir0220 why on pause you can save your values on SharedPrefernce and then get onResume alternativelly save values on SavedInstance and get on Restor

Comment: could you show me an example? 

Also, two guys up there Prmths and codeMagic think that i shoud fix the error message that I am getting in my logcat. What do you say about that?

Comment: @amir0220 you are just inflating layout and adding a view of it to some view either add all view of layout or remove its parent

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that.